# Error while trying to run a .NET program on Linux

Tags: .net, linux

I downloaded the required .NET SDK and Runtime for Linux. After which I created a project
and tried to run the project (sudo dotnet run). But I am getting an error like this:

```
relocation error: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_fatal_printf version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference
```

Linux: Manjaro

.NET version: 6.0